# Better way of finding longest string length in multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, max, nested-lists

I'm currently prototyping in C# because that is the only thing it is good for.
Now i'm learning linq and encountered a syntax nitpick.

```
private List<string> svar1 = new List<string>();
private List<string> svar2 = new List<string>();
private List<string> svar3 = new List<string>();
private List<string> svar4 = new List<string>();
private List<string> svar5 = new List<string>();
... fill lists with data
```

To get the longest string length in all of these lists i do:

```
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>{svar1, svar2, svar3, svar4, svar5};
int ma = lists.Max(lst => lst.Max(str => str.Length));
```

But it seems too long. Shouldn't you be able to write it shorter and perhaps more efficient that this?

Something like:

```
int ma = {svar1, svar2, svar3, svar4, svar5}.Max(lst => lst.Max(str => str.Length));
```

I've watched videos about this linq syntax but it was so long ago i do not remember the syntax. a few internet searches later and i still can't find a good answer to this.

Update: All lists have about 870 items each.

Comment: "I'm currently prototyping in C# because that is the only thing it is good for." hmmmm?

Comment: @SINTER I could see that being all it is good for if you can't even figure out how to find the longest string with it.

Comment: You could `Concat` all of the lists together rather than putting them all in a list of lists and then just call `Max` on that.

Comment: @SINTER I do not like to be locked in. Especially when i do not trust the language owner, which is Microsoft in this case, to do the right thing. I'm also nitpicky about performance. Ask yourself: How many layers is it between c# and the hardware and OS compared to C++ ? How many other programs needs to be running to run C#? Now what is the memory and performance footprint of it including those needed programs ? It is also not a standard. You should also know what it means for a language to be proprietary.

Comment: @Erix Did you read past the first sentence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close;

```
int ma = new[] {svar1, svar2, svar3, svar4, svar5}
             .Max(lst => lst.Max(str => str.Length));
```

should work.

Comment: Ah that's the one, thanks.
This is the fastest solution according to performance tests in my case. All lists have about 870 items each.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Concat instead of creating new List:

```
svar1.Concat(svar2).
   Concat(svar3).
   Concat(svar4).
   Max(str => str.Length);
```

This solution may be slightly faster if you have many short lists.